# Powershell move file back to original path

Tags: powershell

I am working on a code to monitor multiple paths and remove jpg files that are not in the correct color profile. I would like the files to move back to the original path after I have converted the files

The powershell script monitors multiple paths with exiftool:

```
'E:\' + $ComputerName + '\Capture One Session\Output\Market1'
'E:\' + $ComputerName + '\Capture One Session\Output\Market2'
```

If exiftool ProflieDescrtiption is -notlike srgb, the file will be moved to a location for conversion.

```
# If colorSpace is not srgb
If("$colorSpace" -notlike "*srgb*")
{
  # sideline theAsset to the Image Magick conversionStage
  robocopy "$assetsFolder" "$conversionStage" "$theFileName" /mov /xo /R:1 /W:2 /MT:32
}
```

After the file is converted to the proper color profile, I would like the file to move back to its original path (market1 or market2).

What I need help with is figuring out an efficient way to get the jpgs back to their original path (market1 or market2). Please keep in mind the marketplace1 and marketplace2 paths are receiving images from another user as they process the jpgs out. That said there may be multiple jpgs from both locations coming and going at any given time to the `$converstionStage`.